# Regular expression understanding. Get uppercase words. Group sequence

Tags: php, regex

I have a function:

```
public static function getUpperCase($str) {     
    preg_match_all('/([A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-]*[\s])([A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-]*[\s]?)+/', $str, $matches);     
    return $matches[0];
}
```

And when I'm trying to test my string:

> Consider the tale of a Redditor who whether the Google Home had an
>   internal temperature sensor. He was feeling a bit chilly at home and
>   asked the assistant “What's the temperature inside?” He figured that
>   the system would figure out the temperature from his Nest thermostat
>   and report that back to him.

I'm getting the following results:

```
[1]: Google Home
```

How can I get the following:

```
[1]: Consider
[2]: Redditor
[3]: Google Home
[4]: He
[5]: What
[6]: He
[7]: Nest
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `+` quantifier with a star quantifier `*` or go with following simplified version:

```
[A-Z]\w+(?:\s+[A-Z]\w+)*
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/x15frp/1)

Comment: For the sake of simplicity, I used `\w` however if it doesn't fit your needs you may go with your own character class.

Answer (score 0):

@revo's answer is the correct one. But, if you want to keep with your version, check the version below:

`([A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-]*[\s]?)+`

see: http://regexr.com/3h426